# Why do Arrays with implicit undefined values return N-1 length?

Tags: javascript

In the Chrome JavaScript console, when I evaluate the following expression:

`[,,]`

It returns: `[undefined × 2]`

When I evaluate:

`[,,].length;`

It returns `2`.

Why does it not contain 3 undefined values? Is this caused by [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluation?

Comment: A trailing comma is valid, think of `[1,2,].length`

Comment: @elclanrs Are you suggesting this was designed to simplify parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trailing comma in the array definition is ignored. This is what ECMAScript specification says:

> Edition 5 clarifies the fact that a trailing comma at the end of an ArrayInitialiser does not add to the length of the array.

[reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-D) (paragraph 3). And

> Elided array elements are not defined. If an element is elided at the end of an array, that element does not contribute to the length of the Array.

[reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4).

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you put the commas, the browser interprets it as:

```
[undefined,undefined,]
```

Two commas mean there are minimum of two values there but as the user hasn't provided the values, they're coming out to be undefined.. but as the values are there (minimum of two because of two commas) It will give the length two as two undefined values are present.

Remember, it is not an empty array.. an empty array gets defined as [].. again, two commas are telling the browser that the values are undefined, hence you're getting that output.

```
var arr = [,,];
alert(arr[0]); //undefined
alert(arr[1]); //undefined
arr.push(1);
alert(arr[2]); //1
```